# how to set MySql remote database

Tags: mysql

I am a little new with SQL Database and I would like to get it remotely.
I follow many guides and proceeded to the point where I got a server
I opened a database on it (using Cpanel -> phpmyadmin)
and it is accessible from there.

For some reason, I can't use it remotely (or doing it wrong?),
Is there any guide or something I should do before it becomes accessible remotely?

Thanks for the helpers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxgX0.png)

Comment: You need to access phpmyadmin remotely or you want to connect mysql to your application ? If you want to access phpmyadmin [follow this](https://medium.com/@_sathishshan/accessing-remote-database-server-from-local-phpmyadmin-client-97d4bee5242e)

Comment: I want to connect mysql to my web application using API